# Oracle JET how to include data in JS file?

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-jet

I am trying to add Oracle JET timeline to Oracle APEX 21., I added timeline from link below but, I can't load data. https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=timeline&demo=basicTimeline

How to include real data in JavaScript code below?

I tried with `JSON.parse($v(PX_JSON)) -- PX_JSON is item which contain json, but didn't work.`

```
  require(["require", "exports", "knockout", "ojs/ojbootstrap", "text!../cookbook/dataVisualizations/timeline/basicTimeline/seriesOneData.json", "ojs/ojarraydataprovider", "ojs/ojknockout", "ojs/ojtimeline", "ojs/ojformlayout", "ojs/ojbutton"], function (require, exports, ko, ojbootstrap_1, data, ArrayDataProvider) {
      "use strict";
      
      class SeriesModel {
          constructor() {
              this.dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider(JSON.parse(data), {
                  keyAttributes: "id",
              });
              this.overviewValue = ko.observable("on");
              this.orientationValue = ko.observable("horizontal");
              this.currentDateString = "Feb 1, 2010";
              this.currentDate = new Date(this.currentDateString).toISOString();
              this.referenceObjects = [
                  {
                      value: this.currentDate,
                  },
              ];
          }
      }
      ojbootstrap_1.whenDocumentReady().then(() => {
          ko.applyBindings(new SeriesModel(), document.getElementById("timelineContainer"));
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to create a Line Chart in APEX is to do it declaratively. Create a Region, then set the Type to Chart, then under Attributes set the type to Line. You can then generate your Line Chart using a single query and set the settings of the line chart using the other values that appear under Attributes.

You can also install the [Sample Charts](https://github.com/oracle/apex/tree/21.1/sample-apps/sample-charts) app to see some samples and how they are set up.